# PHP sort associative array by numeric key in asc order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

I have a problem with ksort, it is print_r'ing 1 instead of the array.

Here is my array:

```
Array(

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 08:30 am
        [time_id] => 48451
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 09:00 am
        [time_id] => 48452
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 09:30 am
        [time_id] => 48453
    )

)
```

And ksort($array) is vardumping bool(true).  Why is it not sorting my array appropriately?

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
$array = ksort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Read the docs... it returns `true` on success but the array is altered . http://us2.php.net/ksort

Comment: Do not reassign array its return boolean(true/false). See the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it not sorting my array appropriately?

[`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) works on the array directly and returns a [bool](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) - returning `true` on success and `false` otherwise.

`print_r()` outputs `1` (i.e. `true`) because `ksort()` successfully sorted the array.

Don't reassign `$array`.