# How do i loop through reordered array in php/laravel without using the reordered key number

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that has been sorted ($sortProgDetails):

```
items: array:3 [▼
    1 => array:4 [▶]
    0 => array:4 [▶]
    2 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

I then want to loop through it in the way it currently appears but using the key as 0,1,2, not by 1,0,2. How can i achieve this?

Example of the loop where i want to return the row id on item with key = 1, then 0, then 2. so instead of the first $key = 1, i want that to be 0.

```
foreach ($sortProgDetails as $key=>$progDetails) {
     $getCurrentRow = Programmes::where('reference', $sortProgDetails [$key]['reference'])->get()[0]['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop it in the order it is but have a counter, then add it

```
$i=0;
foreach ($sortProgDetails as $key=>$progDetails) {
    //you can use the variable $i here wich will be 0, 1, 2...
    $getCurrentRow = Programmes::where('reference', $progDetails['reference'])->get()[0]['id'];
    $i++; 
}
```

If you want to loop it in the old order, then use the traditional way, with `for()`

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($sortProgDetails); $i++) {
     $getCurrentRow = Programmes::where('reference', $sortProgDetails [$i]['reference'])->get()[0]['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and set the index to retrieve using the counter:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sortProgDetails); $i++) {
  $getCurrentRow = Programmes::where('reference', $sortProgDetails[$i]['reference'])->get()[0]['id'];`
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i think this is all you need and your answer:

you need ksort :

```
ksort($sortProgDetails);
```

look at this link:
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385237/php-sort-associative-array-by-numeric-key-in-asc-order)